# Ruby Extension Data_Wrap_Struct - type Error

Tags: c, ruby

I'm trying to create a C wrapper for a library and I've constructed this code which seems to match most of the examples out there on the web:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ruby.h"
#include "lpsolve/lp_lib.h"


VALUE klass;

void lp_free(lprec *lp) {
  delete_lp(lp);
}

VALUE lp_create(VALUE self, VALUE cols) {
  lprec *lp = make_lp(0, NUM2INT(cols));
  if (lp == NULL) {
    rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "Could not allocate LP Structure");
  }
  return Data_Wrap_Struct(klass, NULL, lp_free, lp);
}


VALUE lp_add_column(VALUE self, VALUE data) {
    lprec *lp;
    Data_Get_Struct(self, lprec, lp);
    return Qnil;
}

void Init_lpsolve_ruby() {
  klass = rb_define_class("LPSolve",    rb_cObject); 
  rb_define_method(klass, "lp_create",  lp_create,     1);
    rb_define_method(klass, "add_column", lp_add_column, 1);
}
```

Followed with:

```
s = LPSolve.new
s.lp_create(5)
s.add_column(5)
```

But I end up with this error:

```
test.rb:7:in `add_column': wrong argument type LPSolve (expected Data) (TypeError)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry - I realized that I needed something else and that klass was probally the correct variable in the call to Data_Wrap_Struct - I've been bouncing between these two for a while.  For the record, I made my change before I saw your response!

Comment: Is your error actually occurring in the above code? It looks like you may have had the code `Data_Get_Struct(klass, lprec, lp);` in `lp_add_column` when that error occured? I think  `Data_Get_Struct(self, lprec, lp);` is correct.

Comment: Yes, I have Data_Get_Struct(self, lprec, lp) - I just re-compiled it one more time to make sure I didn't have any stale builds or anything..

Comment: I think if you want to use a class to wrap a struct with `Data_Wrap_Struct` you need to define your own allocation function with `rb_define_alloc_func`. (Also looking at [the current docs](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/aad3a8679f91420ba1dff6042517d75cbea961ab/doc/extension.rdoc) suggests that `Data_Wrap_Struct` and friends have been deprecated for `TypedData_*`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the function of `Data_Wrap_Struct` and `Data_Get_Struct`. `Data_Wrap_Struct` allocates a new object that wraps the data. The first argument to `Data_Get_Struct` must be an object that was returned from `Data_Wrap_Struct`. Since you do not define a custom allocation function for `LPSolve`, when you call `LPSolve.new` a new instance of `LPSolve` is allocated like any other normal object in ruby (without calling `Data_Wrap_Struct`), and so you cannot pass the resulting object into `Data_Get_Struct`.

Comment: BTW, I bet that this would work with your current C code (might be wrong though): `LPSolve.new.lp_create(5).add_column(5)`

Comment: Thanks, so the whole object needs to be wrapped?

Comment: You just can't make an object that already exists wrap a pointer. The pointer has to be specified when the object is created, not after the fact.